# Just moved to Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04, how do I make activities always visible?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I searched a bit but could not find it anywhere. Where do I make it so I don't have to press that *Activities* button on the top left in order to see my list of apps? either auto hide/show or always visible would be acceptable, but pressing a button is a pain.

Comment: **CV Queue reviewers:** Self-answered.  Leave open!

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? I know I self answered but was hoping to find other solutions. Alternatively I guess I can delete it or mark it as answered.

Comment: It means that someone is trying to close your question, whereas I'm trying to keep it open so you *can accept*  so someone else can benefit from your answer.  CV = Close Vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, install *Gnome Tweak Tool* and enable the *Ubuntu Dock*.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Inside the Tweak Tool set-up go into *Extensions*, then scroll down to *Ubuntu Dock*.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu includes a modified version of a GNOME extension that turns the Activities "dash" into a sort of dock. You should have that installed. Here is how to get at its settings:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-customize-dock-panel-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

However, you may not have it for some reason.

If you don't, you can install the standard set this way:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Alternatively, you might prefer the "full strength" version, which is called "Dash to Dock":

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

If you install the Firefox addon mentioned in my 2nd link, you can add extensions directly from the GNOME extensions site -- including Dash-to-Dock.

If you do that, I find that a few others significantly improve the GNOME 3 experience. I describe them here:

https://liam-on-linux.livejournal.com/57630.html

That may be helpful.